# Text tabbed interface new to Lion

Tags: cocoa, interface, osx-lion, hig

I like the new tab interface displayed in the Lion “About This Mac” window. It's not gorgeous, but I think it's extremely useful in presenting information where icons would most probably fail to do a good job.

Question is: is that UI available from standard Cocoa components? I.e., can something similar to it be built with Xcode, without resorting to custom classes with custom drawing code?

[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't that just a toolbar without images?

Comment: sure it is and selectable items